# Como hago para que un hilo actue de acuerdo a los datos del arreglo

Tags: c#

Tengo el siguiente codigo en c# con windows forms dentro de un boton:

```
new Task(() => {
  Task[] tareas = {

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => metodo1(), CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent, tarea),
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => metodo2(), CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent, tarea)

  };
}).Start();


public void metodo1() {
  for (int v = 0; v < arreglointernet.Length; v++) {
    if (progressBar1.Visible == false) {
      progressBar1.Visible = true;
    }
    if (progressBar1.Value < 100) {
      progressBar1.Value++;
    }

    if (arreglointernet[v].Contains("D")) {

      richTextBox3.Text += arreglointernet[v].ToString() + "\nindex of " + arreglointernet[v].LastIndexOf(";") + "\n" + "Debito de internet aplicado\n";
    } else {
      richTextBox3.Text += arreglointernet[v].ToString() + "\nindex of " + arreglointernet[v].LastIndexOf(";") + "\n" + "credito de internet aplicado\n";

    }



  }

}

public void metodo2() {
  for (int vv = 0; vv < arregloproceso.Length; vv++) {
    if (progressBar1.Visible == false) {
      progressBar1.Visible = true;
    }
    if (progressBar1.Value < 100) {

      progressBar1.Value++;
    }
    if (arregloproceso[vv].Contains("D")) {

      richTextBox3.Text += arregloproceso[vv].ToString() + "\nindex of " + arregloproceso[vv].LastIndexOf(";") + "\n" + "Debito de proces aplicado\n";
    } else {
      richTextBox3.Text += arregloproceso[vv].ToString() + "\nindex of " + arregloproceso[vv].LastIndexOf(";") + "\n" + "credito de proces aplicado\n";

    }
  }

}
```

lo anterior me genera el siguiente resultado despues del metodo 1 o el metodo 2:

Los arreglos con las transacciones estan listos para comenzar con el 
procesoI;C;2000
index of 3
credito de internet aplicado
I;D;1000
index of 3
Debito de internet aplicado

index of -1
credito de internet aplicado
P;C;4000.54
index of 3
credito de proces aplicado
P;D;2000
index of 3
Debito de proces aplicado

index of -1
credito de proces aplicado

index of -1
credito de proces aplicado

Como hago para que no me tome en cuenta esos indexOf  -1 es decir que se detenga el hilo cuando no hay datos en un arreglo ?????

Comment: Hola buenas, podrias decirnos cuales son los valores de entrada, así como los valores de salida esperados para poder entender un poco mejor que es lo que intentas hacer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¿por que no simplemente agregas una condición antes de la asignación ?

```
        richTextBox3.text += ....
```

Estas obteniendo indexof -1  por que tu variable no contiene el carácter

> **";"**

así que lo que tienes que hacer es poner una comparación para saber si la variable contiene el carácter.

```
 if(arreglointernet[v].contains(";"))
 {   
      richTextBox3.text += ....
 }
```

Manejando timer:

una ventaja de los Timers es que estos una vez que son iniciados ejecutaran su proceso en threads secundarios en un intervalo que nosotros elijamos:

bien puedes usar el control desde la barra de herramientas o declarar y crear la instancia desde codigo

Winforms timers:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Timer timer; //declarando la instancia global

    form_load(....)
    {
        timer = new Timer(); //Creando la instancia
        //estos son los parametros que tienes que asignar ya sea en codigo o desde el diseñador

        timer.Enabled = false; // asi el timer no correra desde el inicio 
        timer.Interval = 7000; //7000 milisegundos = 7 segundos
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(Timertick); //el evento que sera invocado cada 7 segundos 
    }

        buttonStartClick()
        {
              timer.Start();//inicia el timer
        } 
         buttonStopClick()
        {
              timer.Stop();//Detiene el timer
        } 

    private  void Timertick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        metodo1();
        metodo2();
    }
```

si tienes problemas con Ambigüedad del timer, tienes que utilizar el **System.Windows.Forms.Timer**. la clase creo que la clase threading también tiene timers, pero esos no son los que necesitas.

Comment: Gracias lo siguiente me soluciono esa parte: if(arreglointernet[v].contains(";")) { richTextBox3.text += .... } pero no me soluciono lo de el Thread.Sleep. Se me pega el programa inclusive usando metodos asincronos y await se me pega

Comment: Osea lo que quiero es que cada 7 segundos se imprima una posicion del arreglo como subproceso

Comment: por que no utilizas un timer job? 
el dispatcher timerjob tiene accesso a los controles del front end, lo puedes crear con un timespan de 7 segundos. 
ahora bien lo que harian tus botones seria detener e iniciar el timerjob , añado de talles a la respuesta